# Specifying the number of times to return object in a chained AndReturn expression with multiple return objects

Tags: java, mocking, easymock

I have a mock, for which I expect `object1` for 1st call and `object2` for next 2 calls.
Is this expression correct?

`EasyMock.expect(result.get(0)).andReturn(object1).andReturn(object2).times(2);`

or should I use

`EasyMock.expect(result.get(0)).andReturn(object1).andReturn(object2).andReturn(object2);`

Specifically, does adding `times` at the end make the entire group of expectations be expected twice, or only the last expectation in the chain?

Comment: Have you tried it? Does the test pass?

Comment: Have you read http://easymock.org/user-guide.html ?

Comment: @JohnJoseph I have updated the question to specify what my actual doubt was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to chain multiple expectations and the expected number of calls.

So the first method indeed works. I have tested it as well.
`EasyMock.expect(result.get(0)).andReturn(object1).andReturn(object2).times(2);`